# Рассчитать количество частиц атома

Tags: олимпиада, логика

Чтобы считать количество мы пользуемся неким детектором, условно ДВИГАТЕЛЬ, который умеет это считать.
Внутри себя коробка хранит число в двоичном виде, разбитое на две части.

Например:

```
dec |  a    b 
39  | 100  111
```

Двигатель на каждое событие инкрементирует (делает +1) в значении b элемента числа до того, как он не переполнится и после этого увеличивает значение а элемента на +1
В общем это счётчик, который хранит значение с разбиением на две части

Мы гарантированно знаем, что за время эксперимента произойдёт не больше событий, чем может сосчитать коробка
Следовательно, можно точно сказать, что в элементе a переполнения никогда не будет в элементе b, соответственно, переполнение это обычное дело, потому что так работает этот счётчик

Получить всё число у двигателя нельзя из-за особенностей реализации (быстрые счётчики знаете ли, сложная штука)
Поэтому нам доступно только две функции у коробки:
get_a и get_b и мы не ограничены в их вызове

Вам необходимо описать логику для того, чтобы получить общее значение счётчика.

Оно должно быть

1. Максимально близкое к последнему возможному моменту времени на момент запроса
2. Точно существовать т.е. отсечь ситуацию, когда мы получили число, а на самом деле в эксперимент закончился и условным атомом было выпущено меньше частиц, чем показывает счётчик. т.е. не уйти в будущее

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Мне кажется, тут много вариантов можно придумать. Но самый простой мне кажется такой:

- a1 = get_a()
- b = get_b()
- a2 = get_a()
- если a2 == a1, значит переполнения между запросами не было, выдаём сцепку a2 и b как результат
- иначе a1 = a2 и переходим на шаг получения b

Comment: а там не b -1 ?

Comment: @Grundy Не понял мысль :)

Comment: @the Я в общем-то согласен, если это может быть проблемой, то этот случай нужно отдельно продумать. Хотя мне кажется в этом случае максимум, что мы можем сделать, это взять `a2` и `b = 0`, больше мы про `b` ничего не можем угадать.

Comment: @CrazyElf верно, спасибо огромное за помощь

Comment: @CrazyElf, взяв первый раз `a` значение `b` увеличилось на 1